# mysql, search table ability

Tags: mysql

I am creating a website where I list possible unique/distinct values found in each of the columns. 
The user would select the values and execute a search.

Two Methods I was thinking of:

1> on the go, when the user selects a table, i will run a series of distinct commands for each column.
I noticed there is a slow down on this method but doesn't involve much work from me

2> create some kind of option list for each column and save into some kind of file. This seems to be the fastest method for user but involves some work to create this table summary file of distinct values.

can someone propose a good solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third option would be to reconsider your database design.  If you have columns where the information is repetitious, then it would probably make sense to create additional tables that store the actual value, and then in your 'main' table only store the id that links back.

Then you can store the unique value in the relational table and just call each of those related tables to create your dropdown.

For example, say you have a table

```
Users
user_id
fname
lname
city
state
zip
favorite_color
```

If you were going to grab the distinct values for city and favorite color you will need to go through all of your rows to determine that information.  So, you end up with N * Fields scans of your data to populate your table using method 1.

If you instead created a layout where you had two additional tables:

```
City
city_id
city_name

favorite_color
favorite_color_id
color_name
```

And then modified your users table to be

```
Users
user_id
fname
lname
city_id
state
zip
favorite_color_id
```

Then you've done a couple of things.  First, if you needed all the cities and colors, you'd only be going through X records, where X is the unique number of cities / colors.  Additionally the overall size of your table Users  will end  up smaller because instead of storing  strings  over and over, you're just storing an id that takes up less space.

In the end you end up with a much more robust solution that is more scalable than what you have right  now with the approaches you were already considering.